# How to apply @Html.Raw to each of the SelectListItem.Text properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to apply style property to my selectlistitem text, which is static in razor html.

Comment: You cant, and in any case its the browser/OS that generates the appearance of a `<select>` element and its `<option>` elements an you have very little control over its styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styled select boxes can only be done by the help of javascript libraries which usually hides the original select element and create a styled div over it which looks like a dropdown.

If you really want to show your dropdowns with a customized style, try searching in Google for "jquery select plugins".

We usually use https://select2.github.io/. Easy to use and very flexible.